# stopping terminal command gnome-open from opening files as maximised

Tags: gnome, wmctrl, devilspie

when I use the terminal command 'gnome-open' for opening files it causes them to always open as maximised, this is a problem because in its maximised form I can't change its position and size using 'wmctrl', which is something I need to do. I've checked that when manually changed from maximised window, the wmctrl written in the terminal (unfortunately not from script yet) works beautifully.

How do I change a window from maximised to a small window? or open with gnome-open in a way that won't cause them to be maximised in the first place?

This is in ubuntu linux,would like it to work smoothly for a bash script and they are GUI windows